# How to center a form using showdialog (.NET Compact Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I want to centre a popup form launched using Form.ShowDialog() in .NET Compact Framework. I dont see any property like StartPosition in .NET CF Form object.

Can someone please suggest me how to centre popups in .NET CF 3.5?

Comment: Try other properties See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944897/show-a-child-form-in-the-centre-of-parent-form-in-c

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make an extension method that does the work for you:

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static void CenterForm(this Form theForm)
    {
        theForm.Location = new Point(
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2 - theForm.Width / 2,
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2 - theForm.Height / 2);
    }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
TheDialogForm f = new TheDialogForm();
f.CenterForm();            
f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: This is not working! I still see the form being randomly placed on the screen.

Comment: @Gopinath: that's odd; I tried out the code before posting it. Is there any other code setting the `Location` or `Bounds` property of the form?

Comment: thanks fredrik. When tested on  the device, the popup centered as expected. But when the application was ran on a PC, it did not center properly.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

If you want your popup form appear in center of screen by default you can just set a starting position for it in form properties, it should sound like 'Center parent'.

Something like this:

```
form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

Comment: As noted in the question, the `StartPosition` property is not available in the .NET Compact Framework.

Comment: damn me! i won't answer on stuff which i used that long ago.. really :)

Answer (score 6):

If Parent is not defined for the Dialog then use

```
login.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
login.ShowDialog();
```

where login is the `Form` Object

or you can also use if you are calling on top of an existing Parent `Form`

```
login.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
login.ShowDialog();
```

This property can also be set in the Property dialog of the `Form`, if you think that the property is always the same for you. By default it should be set to CenterParent, which will not work in case you are invoking your `Form` before the Parent `Form` in some cases, like Login screen for the first time etc.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old post, but I had the same problem and I solved with this way:

I create an Interface:

```
public interface FormExtensions
    {
        void CenterForm(Form forma);
    }
```

After I did implements the interface on my class:

```
    public partial class frmFirma : Form, FormExtensions
    {
        public frmFirma()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void CenterForm(Form forma)
        {
            forma.Location = new Point(
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2 - forma.Width / 2,
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2 - forma.Height / 2);
        }
    }
```

Then I can crate a instance of the: "frmFirma" an call the method "CenterForm":

```
private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Formas.frmFirma firma = new Formas.frmFirma();
            firma.CenterForm(firma);
            firma.ShowDialog();     
        }
```

I hope this works for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Set the left and Top properties on the  of the form in 'frmDialog_Activated event

```
Private Sub frmDialog_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
        Me.Left = (frmMain.Width - Me.Width) / 2 ' AS Your Wish
        Me.Top = (frmMain.Height - Me.Height) / 2 + 165 '' AS Your Wish
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the easiest way

```
Form f= new AmrDealForm();
f.CenterToScreen();
f.ShowDialog();
```