# How to call new form over first form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a problem because I'd like to call `newProjectNewFrom` over top `Form1` that is a main form. If run my program the new windows will be hide under `From1`. The Form1 is  `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;`

```
private void NewProjectMainMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 newProjectNewForm = new Form2();
   newProjectNewForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

[image: current situation]

I'd like to get following situation
[image: goal]

Comment: Did you check if **form1** has set [topMost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx) property to true?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944897/show-a-child-form-in-the-centre-of-parent-form-in-c-sharp

Comment: Normally, if you parent the dialog form correctly, it will do what you want (well, you still need to set the `StartPosition` property correctly). That means passing `this` to `ShowDialog()`: i.e. `newProjectNewForm.ShowDialog(this);` Note that you normally should _not_ need to set `TopMost`.

Comment: Glad I could help@meernet - perhaps you may consider voting my answer up - and/or selecting it as best answer.

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz - perhaps you may consider voting my question ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So then - here is it as an answer. I think you've set [TopMost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `form1` to **true**.

As *MSDN* mentions

> A topmost form is a form that overlaps all the other (non-topmost)
>   forms even if it is not the active or foreground form. Topmost forms
>   are always displayed at the highest point in the z-order of the
>   windows on the desktop. You can use this property to create a form
>   that is always displayed in your application, such as a Find and
>   Replace tool window.

Just set it to false, and it should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing `Form1` as owner inside `ShowDialog`? like this? -

```
private void NewProjectMainMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 newProjectNewForm = new Form2();
   newProjectNewForm.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

as mentioned in msdn here? - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe(v=vs.110).aspx

> Note: Give a little bit more time to reading documentations. Don't
>   just ask questions for such an easy answer.