# How to set a child form in centre of parent form?

Tags: c#

I'd like to do the same as this:

[Show a child form in the centre of Parent form in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944897/show-a-child-form-in-the-centre-of-parent-form-in-c-sharp)

But at any moment, not only at start.

Reason is because I show and hide a form. So this only work on first show because after that it is just hidden, so I don't "Start" it again.

Comment: `if (ParentForm != null) 
        Location = new Point((ParentForm.Size.Width - Size.Width) / 2, (ParentForm.Size.Height - Size.Height) / 2);`

Comment: I see, there is no built in function?

Comment: I doubt if there's a function for one line expression.

Comment: thanks, I ended up doing this. You just lack this.Location.X to add to x coordinate and same thing for Y coordinate. If you post it as answer I'll mark it

Answer (score 0):

C# code to show subForm in center of this (this form is papa of subForm)

```
frmSub fs=new frmSub();
fs.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
fs.Parent = this;
fs.Show();
```

Comment: this would work but make a new form every time, I need to just show hide it

Answer (score 0):

Try this and keep the `FormBorderStyle` of the parent form to `FixedSingle` so that it's not resizable.

Say, suppose you do this on a `button1_Click()` event and just declare `Form f2 = new Form();` above the event. And set the start position of the child form to `CenterScreen` like this:

```
f2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

Using a `checkBox` you can show/hide the child form easily.

```
Form f2 = new Form();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.IsMdiContainer = true;            
    //Form f2 = new Form(); To prevent creating a new form everytime.
    f2.MdiParent = this;
    f2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
        f2.Hide();
    else
        f2.Show();
}
```

Comment: this work but make a new form every time, I need to just show hide it

Comment: come again...what do you want to hide?

Comment: form.Hide() instead of closing it so it always remains active. Then form.Show() when I want to show it

Comment: hmmm trying it with few tweaks, exactly same code, form just doesn't show