# Form opening on top-left of screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform that I would like to open on the centre of the parent form, which is already a `mdiChild` (i.e. I cannot set is `mdiContainer` on the parent). Below is the code I use. The form I create always opens on the top-left corner of whichever parent I assign to it, which is frustrating...

```
        loadingCircle = new Loading(Title);
        loadingCircle.TopLevel = false;
        loadingCircle.Parent = this;
        loadingCircle.Show();
        loadingCircle.BringToFront();
```

I have got the `StartPosition` switched to `CenterParent` in the designer, however it does not seem to do anything...

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944897/show-a-child-form-in-the-centre-of-parent-form-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to the center of the screen,

You can use either :

```
   loadingCircle.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

Or :

### loadingCircle.ShowDialog();

or try this code to find center position:

```
  Form loadingCircle = new frmLoading();
        loadingCircle.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        loadingCircle.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + (this.Width - loadingCircle.Width) / 2, this.Location.Y + (this.Height - loadingCircle.Height) / 2);
        loadingCircle.Show(this);
```

Comment: I don't want to use ShowDialog() because I still want the user to be able to interact with the UI. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I used a slight variation, but yes it did work!

                loadingCircle = new LoadingCircle(RegisterTitle);
                loadingCircle.TopLevel = false;
                loadingCircle.Parent = this;
                Point startPosition = new Point((this.Parent.Width / 2 - loadingCircle.Width / 2), (this.Parent.Height / 2 - loadingCircle.Height / 2));
                loadingCircle.Location = startPosition;
                loadingCircle.Show();
                loadingCircle.BringToFront();