# Position form where the last form used was positioned

Tags: c#, winforms, position

Let's say I have 2 movable forms and when I click a button in one form (the fist one which has it's start position CenterScreen) it brings me to another one (but the second one has still centerscreen start position) and let's say I move the first form before I press the button and when I click the button I want to position the new form where I moved my first form... how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this following code,
set `StartupPosition = Manual` then the Left and Top values (Location) set via the this code

Code for the Form1

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace PositioningCs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm2=new Form2();
            frm2.setLocation(this.Top,this.Left);
            frm2.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the Form2

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace PositioningCs
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private int top_val=0;
        private int left_val=0;
        public void setLocation(int top_val,int left_val)
        {
              this.top_val=top_val;
              this.left_val=left_val;
        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Top = top_val;
            this.Left = left_val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this works, but I want at the first *first form* load to be in the center screen how can I do this/

Comment: Then set `StartupPosition=CenterScreen`, then automatically it will open in the center screen

Answer (score 0):

you can relate position with position of parent form...

`//if "this" is Form1, in the button event to call Form2...
 ...
 Form2.Position = this.Position;
 Form2.ShowDialog(this);`

in this link you can find more details: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944897/show-a-child-form-in-the-centre-of-parent-form-in-c-sharp)

i hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Remember the position of a form after it's moved and re-use it later.

```
private static Point location = null;

private void MyForm_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   location = this.Location;
}

private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (location != null) {  this.Location = location; }
}
```