# Center form in parent only having the parentWnd

Tags: c#, winforms, solidworks

i'm working with the [Solidworks Pdm Api](https://help.solidworks.com/2019/English/api/epdmapi/ReleaseNotes-epdmapi.html) and i'm developing an addin using Windows Forms to show information about some files.

In the api docs, recommend to use this class to set the Pdm window as parent

```
public class WindowHandle : IWin32Window
{
    private IntPtr mHwnd;

    public WindowHandle(int hWnd)
    {
        mHwnd = new IntPtr(hWnd);
    }
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { return mHwnd; }
    }
}
```

And it works well, so, when i will show my form, i'm doing the next

```
//i recived hWnd parameter from the api
WindowHandle myHandle = new WindowHandle(hWnd);
var weForm = new myForm();
weForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
weForm.ShowDialog(myHandle);
```

At this point, the form shows without problem, the Pdm Window is effectively the parent, but the Form is not centered.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944897/show-a-child-form-in-the-centre-of-parent-form-in-c-sharp) about how to center forms in his parent, but apparently anyone work when you use a custom class inherited from `IWin32Window`.

What can i do to center my form?

Comment: It's not the Parent, it's the Owner. Can you get meaningful values from `this.Owner` in `weForm.Load`? Also, try calling [GetWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) (the results are also *dependable*, the function is not DPIAware)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the auto-centering feature isn't working then you'll need to do the math yourself.

The math basically means that you align the center points of each window.

```
int left = parentBounds.Left + (parentBounds.Width / 2) - (childBounds.Width / 2);
int right = parentBounds.Top + (parentBounds.Height / 2) - (childBounds.Height / 2);
```